# In Tableau, I have values by year, but I need values by decade. How do I bin or create a group of years to create that?

Tags: tableau-desktop, bins

In Tableau, I have values (of NO3) by year, but I need values by decade. How do I bin or create a group of years to create that? Dates data is date plus time if that's relevant.

I feel like I should be able to easily merge the highlighted dates together, but I don't see where I can do that. I've tried doing a calculated field, but I'm not entirely sure how that works.

[image: Tableau screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

### Grouping

Hover your selected fields and click the paperclip looking icon to [create a group](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/sortgroup_groups_creating.htm#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Data%20pane%2C%20right,group%2C%20and%20then%20click%20Group.).

### Create Custom Buckets via a Calculated Field

Create a calculated field called `[Decades]` and using an if statement conditionally segment your data. How this would look right now with your current data:

```
IF YEAR([Date Smp]) >= 1990 AND YEAR([Date Smp]) <= 1999 THEN '90s'
ELSEIF YEAR([Date Smp]) >= 2000 AND YEAR([Date Smp]) <= 2010 THEN '2000s'
ELSEIF ...
END
```

**EDIT** An easier variation of this approach is to create a calculated field called Year defined as `YEAR([Date Amp])` Then right click on that new field in the data pane (left margin) and Create a Histogram bin field with a bin size of 10. Name it Decade.

Decade will display as the first year of a decade, which might not be as readable but is simple.

Another variation to get more readable decade values - instead of letting Tableau automatically create the bin field, make it yourself with some simple math such as `STR(YEAR([Date Amp]) / 10 * 10) + "'s"` That way you don't have to hard code decade boundaries and your code will work forever :-)

Drag `[Decades]` out to your columns shelf.

Comment: I went with the calculated field approach and it worked (first time in tableau using a calculated field). I'll try the other options when I have more time and report back.